# Can't find Lubuntu option alongside Mac OS X

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, uefi

I just installed Lubuntu 14.04 on my old Macbook. The installer said that it was unable to install the bootloader onto any device, so I proceeded with the installation without installing bootloader anywhere. I then ran Boot-Repair and "fixed" the bootloader issue before rebooting. Now, when I press the `Alt` key, I can find the `Macintosh HD` and `EFI boot` (USB stick) options, but not the installed Lubuntu as an option. In addition, selecting the `EFI boot` option now crashes and immediately boots up Mac OS X.

Here's the [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15100809) from Boot-Repair. Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got a mixed BIOS-mode/EFI-mode installation. These can be tricky, although on average they're less tricky on Macs than on PCs. Nonetheless, using a BIOS-mode GRUB to boot OS X will be difficult to impossible. Your easiest course of action is likely to be to install my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) in OS X. Once installed, it *should* detect your Lubuntu installation and enable you to boot it directly. (It will probably also offer an option to boot Lubuntu via the GRUB on `/dev/sdb`, which might or might not work.) If you can boot directly (via the `boot\vmlinuz-*` options), you can remove the redundant or non-functional BIOS-mode GRUB by editing `refind.conf`: Uncomment the `scanfor` line and ensure that `hdbios` is *not* among the options.

One caveat: If you're running OS X 10.11 ("El Capitan"), you'll have to jump through some extra installation hoops, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html)

One final comment: Your `/dev/sda` has a [hybrid MBR.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) This is ugly, unnecessary, and dangerous. I recommend you replace it with a conventional protective MBR. Doing any trivial operation on the disk with GParted will do this; or you can use `gdisk`: Type `x` to enter the experts' menu, followed by `n` to create a new protective MBR, and then `w` to save the changes. Your `/dev/sdb` uses an MBR (with no GPT). This is unusual in the context of a Mac, but it should be fine and cause no real problems if you follow my advice. I can't say how GRUB or the Mac's built-in boot loader would react to the mixture of GPT on the first disk and MBR on the second, though.

---

**EDIT:**

Oh, wait. I hit the post button when I realized something: You have no [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) This complicates matters. There are at least three possible ways to proceed:

- Install rEFInd from OS X, but do so by running the `refind-install --notesp` command (adding the `--notesp` option). This will install rEFInd to the main OS X partition on `/dev/sda2`.
- Convert `/dev/sdb` from MBR to GPT (by running `gdisk` on the disk) and make `/dev/sdb1` your ESP by giving it a type code of EF00 (in `gdisk`; this is called a "boot flag" in `parted` and GParted). You should then be able to install rEFInd with its default options, which will put it on your ESP (`/dev/sdb1`). Note that this approach presupposes that `/dev/sdb1` is not currently being used for anything else. (Based on its size and location, it does look like it might have been intended as an ESP at some point.)
- Use `gdisk` or GParted to create an ESP on `/dev/sda`. There's enough room before `/dev/sda1` for an ESP, so I suspect that one might have existed there at one point but been deleted. In any event, if you use GParted for this (make it FAT32 and give it a "boot flag"), it will also remove the hybrid MBR. You can then install rEFInd normally and it will be installed to the ESP on `/dev/sda` (probably `/dev/sda1`).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Installing rEFInd into OS X using 'refind-install --notesp' worked wonders. I still can't seem to fix the hybrid MBR issue for my HDD dedicated to Mac OS X, though. I'll keep trying to see if I can change that without losing any data!

Comment: I'm glad that worked. If you're having trouble removing a hybrid MBR, post a new question (I don't see any that directly address the issue) and post another comment here to point me to it. I can elaborate on the solution there.